# Not iterating over my entire array from my for()

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, for-loop, ecmascript-next

I am writing an app in React, meanwhile I was playing with some of the new ECMA 17 features trying to get a little more familiar.  Originaly in a parent Component I used Map() to itterate a new div for every index in my array.

For a new component though a child of the Map one, I thought I would use the Object.enteries()  using the for (){}  format instead of Map.   I thought I could simply return the values that way however it only partially is working.

The problem I am getting is it will only iterate over the first index of my array.  It only console logs and returns the div of the first index in the array.  I am completely lost as to why this is only partially working.

```
import React from 'react';

const InnerCard = (props) => {
    // const myInnerOptions = 
    const myInnerOptions = props.cardSelected  
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myInnerOptions)) {
        console.log(`key: ${key} Card Value: ${value} this is from 
          InnerCards.js`);
        return (
            <div key={key}>inside innerCard: {value}</div>
        )
     }  /*  NOTE  at this point I am having a problem. 
          // thos will only print 1 div   it will only  push the first key  
          //   div out  not the second.  props should be pushing an array of 
               2 items up.  */

     console.log(props.cardSelected, 'here here');
         //for (let [key, value] of Object.entries())

     return (
         <div>{myInnerOptions}</div>

     );
 }

 export default InnerCard;
```

it consoles at the end only the first index and value of the array.
I did notice though the very first console log is...
[] "here here"
which means inbetween my const and before the return ()  that console.log is acting first before any of the parent components.  Is my problem that I need to use a componentWillMount()  at this point?   Obviously it still works as when I click on a div  it is passing the first index in,  so I am thinking asynchronism isnt at play here.. but I am still so green horn that... Ive come to a stand still here  tryignt of igure out  ...

why am I only going over the first index of the array only and not the 2nd?  Is it my for()?
(maybe this isn't enough of my code to help.. insufecient data for a meaningful answer) (sorry long winded..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is when the `for` reach the first return, is not going to continuing painting the other divs.

Basically, when you call `return`, the render function is going to finalize there. The difference with a map is that it returns the child when they have mapped.

What you are doing is basically this:

```
if (true) {
  return 'Something';
}

// Any coding at this point is not going to be executed.
```

The same applies to the for cycle.

Comment: .. so I am going over the first array and then.  pop.  done.   I was going off of an example that I thought pertained to what I was trying to do.  However that example must have only been intended to return if true.  
    const cars = {BMW: 3, Tesla: 2, Toyota: 1};
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(cars)) { console.log(`key: 
        ${key} value: ${value} `)
    }
That being a for() means it kicks out once true,  this is different than for each loop then?  
  
essentially I should probably just return the Map() method then yes? what i am trying to do is not for for()

Comment: Yes, you should use the map instead.

Comment: thank you.  I already just did 
    
   ` const myInnerOptions = props.cardSelected.map((cardSelected, 
        index) => {
  return (
   <div key={cardSelected.toString() + 'aaa'} onClick={() 
                                => this.clickHandler(index)}>
    card {cardSelected} and index {index}
   </div>
  );
 })`
Map() it is.  just trying new things and failing miserably repeatedly.. best kind of learning curve i suppose.  thanks. (got to figure out this comment  code  thing in the future.. eye sore.